# Small PWM module?

Tags: arduino, pwm

I'm trying to find a fitting module/component for a project, but have a hard time finding the right thing.

I need a PWM module/component that can provide a PWM signal and can be controlled via Arduino, preferably TX/RX.

I've used [this one](https://protosupplies.com/product/xy-lpwm-pwm-signal-generator-module/) previously, and it works great, but it is bulky due to the screen and buttons which I don't really need.

It would be perfect to find the same module but without the screen and buttons.

What it needs to do:

- Duty cycle 0-100%
- Frequency 1-10 kHz
- 5 V preferably
- Communication via tx/rx or other Arduino compatible protocol
- 1-2 channels
- As small as possible

I've seen some Adafruit modules, but they have at least 16 channels which is not necessary. Would also work, but if I can find an even smaller alternative that would be great.

Any suggestions?

(And no, the Arduino's PWM signals do not work in my case.)

Comment: IMO, your question should be asked at [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, good idea. Thank you!

Comment: seeking recommendations for things like this is off-topic. please read [ask]

Comment: You could create your own PWM signals.

Comment: I will not post as anwser but as commet to question. You need PWM extender, like GPIO extender? Those chips are actually LED Drivers. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277848/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pwm-expander-like-there-is-a-gpio-expander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Arduino `analogWrite()` can't do what you want without trickery, but most Arduino *hardware* can, so there's no real need for a separate PWM IC or module; you just need to code the Arduino's MCU's timer peripheral to do what you want.

You can do that "by hand", but I would try first to see if an alternative library like [TimerOne](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/timerone/) can get you the PWM you specify. For SAMD21-based Arduinos there is [this library](https://github.com/ocrdu/Arduino_SAMD21_turbo_PWM) (that I wrote), among others.

If you insist on having a separate module for your PWM, just google around (modules exist, but recommendations are *not done* here), or simply use a second Arduino of your choice as a dedicated PWM generator.

Comment: Ok, will look into the other libraries you linked. Thank you. Sorry for posting something off topic / wrong. Appreciate the feedback anyway.

Comment: @Jan-Erik-Runge: No problem, it's just the rules. Please accept the answer (if you accept it) so the question doesn't stay open.